# How does Dynamic Programming help in the subset sum problem to reduce time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

In the Subset Sum problem, if we don't use the Dynamic Programming approach, then we have an exponential time complexity. But if we draw the recursion tree, it seems that all the 2^n branches are unique. If we use dynamic programming, how can we assure that all the unique branches are explored? If there really exists 2^n possible solutions, how does dynamic programming reduce it to polynomial time while also ensuring all 2^n solutions are explored?

Comment: It *doesn't* explore all 2^n solutions, because for this problem you don't have to. This problem (and all problems that can be solved more efficiently with DP than without it) have the property of *optimal substructure*: It can be proven that *every* valid solution consists of a valid solution to a subproblem, plus one more chosen item. The particular subproblem depends on the item chosen, but only through the "remaining weight" parameter -- and since there are only W+1 values that "remaining weight" could take, there are only W+1 subproblems per item that ever need to be solved.

Comment: Dynamic programming reduces the problem to **pseudo**-polynomial time. For example, it converts the complexity of subset sum from O(2^N) to O(NS), where S is the target sum. That's not an improvement if S > 2^N. The key point is that you would only use dynamic programming when you know that S is much smaller than 2^N.

Comment: @j_random_hacker In this case, how can we say that the subproblems overlap?

Comment: The algorithm computes the answer for all weights up to the target W. The subproblems considered are parameterised by two things: The subset of allowed elements, which is always a subset {0, 1, ..., i} for some i, and the target weight j. The solution to subproblem (i, j) is TRUE if either the the solution to subproblem (i-1, j) is TRUE (meaning we don't need to use item i) OR the solution to subproblem (i-1, j-w[i]) is TRUE (meaning we can use item i to get to this weight). So the (i-1, j-w[i]) solution is used in computing solutions to *two* larger subproblems: (i, j) and (i, j-w[i]).

Answer (score 2):

> How does dynamic programming reduce it to polynomial time while also ensuring all 2^n solutions are explored?

It is **pseudo** polynomial time, not polynomial time. It's a very important distinction. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), A numeric algorithm runs in pseudo-polynomial time if its running time is a polynomial in the *numeric value* of the input, but **not necessarily in the length of the input**, which is the case for polynomial time algorithms.

> What does it matter?

Consider an example [1, 2, 3, 4], sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10.

There does in fact exist 2^4 = 16 subsequences, however, do we need to check them all? The answer is no, since we are only concerned about the sum of subsequence. To illustrate this, let's say we're iterating from the 1st element to the 4th element:

1st element:

We can choose to take or not take the 1st element, so the possible sum will be [0, 1].

2nd element:

We can choose to take or not to take the 2nd element. Same idea, possible sum will be [0, 1, 2, 3].

3rd element:

We have [0, 1, 2, 3] now. We now consider taking the third element.  But wait... If we take the third element and add it to 0, we still get 3, which is already present in the array, do we need to store this piece of information? Apparently not. In fact, we only need to know whether a sum is possible at any stage. If there are multiple subsequences summing to the same value, we **ignore** it. This is the key to the reduction of complexity, *if you consider it as a reduction*.

With that said, a real polynomial solution for subset sum is not known since it is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness)

Comment: Do you mean to say [0, 1, 2, 3] if you consider second element?

Comment: @SomeDude Yes, thanks for pointing it out.